# Ubuntu IoT 19.10 on Raspberry 3 Model B

Tags: networking, wireless

Before: I am really familiar with many Linux OS and have knowledge also about Ubuntu, but as of now, Ubuntu IoT is an opportunity. Even the Canonical contacted online and via phone, did not bring up a solution. I am working with Linux since more than 20 years now, with Raspberry Pi now over a year.

I just installed Ubuntu IoT on a new micro SD card (32 GB) and started the Raspi with it. That's so far ok.

Now I need to get network, so WiFi access, as this is the only possibility to go on internet.

For this: The official documentation says: Please install network-manager.
So I did:
sudo snap install network-manager

The point here is, Ubuntu tries to connect any repos in order to get the files?!?!?

What to do next?

Edit: Is there an easy way to enable and config WiFi via command line?

Comment: check repository list inside `/etc/snap/sources.list`. Also, you could try to install `network-manager` with `apt` instead of `snap`

Comment: damadam - I need to know the necessary packages. The raspberry does NOT have network access! Read exactly! and yes, I already tried to install network-manager on both ways. I need to tell Ubuntu IoT the Wifi connection SSID and password - before!!

Comment: you could use `apt-cache rdepends network-manager` to know all packages dependency of `network-manager`

Comment: Ok, really got a list. But that's a joke, isn't it? ubuntu-mate-desktop lubuntu-desktop in the dependencies? Lol. With Raspbian, it would already run in a project! 

You are so little, it's such a joke!

Comment: `network-manager` is the default package that manage network in each desktop, and it had a graphical window, that's why you could find `ubuntu-mate-desktop` or `lubuntu-desktop` in his dependencies (so there is for Gnome, Mate, Xfce, Lxde, KDE desktop management - and probably another one that I forgot)

Comment: So there is no easy way to get a network configuration? I think about any manual configuration in text files.

Comment: It probably can work without these *useless* packages (on a Raspberry) that didn't fit for the desktop, but because I'm not a specialist of Raspberry, I couldn't help more

Comment: there is also this [link](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi?_ga=2.192518702.52390430.1572270011-1138844242.1572270011) that provide steps to install Ubuntu IoT, I shared it *even if I think it's not really usefull for you*

Comment: You may not know, but IoT was designed from Ubuntu server, so, there is by definition a chance of making that without desktop. Let's wait for other people.